# Sharepoint 2013 app user Guid

Tags: userid, sharepoint-2013

i am having little problem in getting Sharepoint Userid (GUID) in SP App 2013.
so far i am getting Sharepoint user's Email address and his Full name using userProfile class of Sharepoint (SP.UserProfile.js).

i needed to get Unique id of the user which we say GUID.. i used below code for that , but everytime i get random so called Guid of the same User.(ehich is definitely not unique id of user).
How can i get sharepoint's user id that is unique on every login.

Please Help!

Thanks

Here is my code snippet

```
    var targetUser;
    var userProps;
    var contxt_web = null;
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    /** Get id of Current SP User*/

    contxt_web = clientContext.get_web();      
    clientContext.load(contxt_web);

    /***/

    peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);      

    userProps = peopleManager.getMyProperties(targetUser);

    clientContext.load(userProps);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);

}

function onRequestSuccess() {

    var messageText = "Name : " + userProps.get_displayName()
                               + " Sharepoint-ID : " + contxt_web.get_id()
                               + " Email : " + userProps.get_email();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using userprops.get_userId ,it may works..